OCR con Tesseract español no guarda acentos en archivo de salida
Estoy usando teseract para reconocér imágens que estan en español.
Usé el artículo de del sitio.
Bajé un diccionario mas adecuado y lo instalé como spa_8
En mi caso mejoró mucho, pero no logro que en el archivo de salida me guarde los acentos y las eñes.  Como si no reconociera el utf-8
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Leemos la imagen utilizando PIL
    image = Image.open(os.path.join('./images', row['File Name']))
    # Realizamos OCR sobre la imagen utilizando pytesseract
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang="spa_8")
    # Escribimos el texto en un archivo .txt
    with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(text + '\n\n')

Pero en la salida me dió lo siguiente:
Identificaci�n del entomo, medio o dispositivo que puede contener evidencia.

Repuesta correcta: � Preservaci�n del entorno, medio o dispositivo objeto de evidencia digital.
Identificaci�n del entomo, medio o dispositivo que puede contener evidencia.
Presentaci�n de los hallazgos obtenidos a trav�s de un informe pericial ante las partes interesadas.

Justificaci�n: Las respuestas correctas son: "Identificaci�n del entorno, medio o dispositivo que puede contener evidencia�, "Preservaci�n del entomo, medio o dispositivo objeto de evidencia digital" y "Presentaci�n de los hallazgos
obtenidos a trav�s de un informe pericial ante las partes interesadas". El proceso de an�lisis de evidencias digitales contempla las etapas de identificaci�n, preservaci�n, an�lisis y presentaci�n de los hallazgos obtenidos. La
identificaci�n tiene que ver con la identificaci�n 

¿Como lo puedo solucionar?
Me parece que estoy muy cerca!!!

¿Has probado con  with open('output.txt', 'a', encoding="utf-8") ?

PERFECTO !!! Era eso !!! Sabía que me faltaba algo!!!

PERFECTO !°!!!! Era Eso !!! GRACIAS !!!!!

Yo soy muy cansino con esto, pero por norma general, siempre se debe especificar explícitamente el encoding al abrir un archivo. Si no se hace, éste depende de la plataforma donde se ejecuta el script, lo cual suele traer problemas. En Linux y MAC, por lo general puedes esperar UTF-8, hoy en día es prácticamente el estándar, igual que en la Web, pero Windows es otra historia... Esto cambiara (con suerte) en Python 3.15, dónde se forzará UTF-8 como encoding por defecto de forma consistente en todo Python, incluido este caso.
